# How come XQuartz/X11 makes the file explorer called with tk_choose.files look like this?

Tags: r, rstudio, macos-high-sierra, xquartz, tcltk

MacOS: High Sierra, version 10.13.6
R version: 3.6.1
R studio verison: 1.2.1335

I have been using Anaconda to manage my R packages for a while now. However, I keep getting errors in regards to C and Fortran compilers when trying to install and run packages that depend on them through the Anaconda R studio distribution. Thus I started using the stand-alone version of R studio again. I use the `tcltk` package in pretty much all of my scripts to easily choose file paths to load multiple data sets etc. When using the `tcltk::tk_choose.files()` command through the Anaconda R studio distribution, the file explorer window looks like the standard file explorer in MacOS. However, when using the same command in the stand-alone version the file explorer looks like this when running through XQuartz/X11:
[image]

My question is why the file explorer suddenly looks this "old" and if there is a way to fix it so I can continue using `tcltk`? Otherwise are there any alternatives?

I have tried out `rJava` together with `rChoiceDialogs` but I cannot get the `rChoiceDialogs::jchoose.files()` to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Meaning the file explorer looks normal again. I uninstalled my R, RStudio, and XQuartz. I then reinstalled all three using homebrew following the guide posted [here](https://swvanderlaan.github.io/post/getting-r-with-tcl-tk-on-my-mac/).